# Add top-level menu pointing to a different custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I have a situation where I want to add a second custom top-level menu for a custom post type.

So, when we have a CPT named "fruits", which registers a top level menu with a label of "Fruits", clicking on "Fruits" will take you to `edit.php?post_type=fruits`.

I'm trying to add a separate top-level menu with a label of "Oranges", and when I click that, it actually goes to `'edit.php?post_type=fruits&subtype=orange'`. However, when adding the new menu the link always wants to point to "admin.php"...how can I get it to point to the edit url above?

edit:  this seems to work , not sure if it's the best way or not:
This actually seems to do the trick, not sure if it's the best way though:

```
add_menu_page('Oranges', 'Oranges', 'edit_posts', 'edit.php?post_type=fruits&subtype=oranges', '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as noted in the edit:

This actually seems to do the trick, not sure if it's the best way though:

```
add_menu_page('Oranges', 'Oranges', 'edit_posts', 'edit.php?post_type=fruits&subtype=oranges', '');
```